# Return function parameter with its default values

Tags: javascript, node.js, arguments, parameter-passing, default-value

I'm looking for an alternative to arguments[0] which gets the first parameter that was passed into the function. Instead I'd like to get the first parameter filled with its default values.

```js
function myFunc ({
  a = 'a',
  b = 'b',
  c = 'c'
} = {}) {
  console.log(arguments[0]);
}

myFunc(); // I would like it to log: {a: 'a', b: 'b', c: 'c'} instead of undefined
```

Any ideas ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You could take a simple variable for the parameter and assign defaults and take the destructuring later.

```js
const
    myFunc = o => {
        o = Object.assign({ a: 'a', b: 'b', c: 'c' }, o);
        const { a, b, c } = o;
        console.log(o);
    };

myFunc();
myFunc({ a: 1 });
myFunc({ x: 1 });
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

[Arrow function does not have `arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

> An arrow function expression is a syntactically compact alternative to
> a regular function expression, although without its own bindings to
> the this, arguments, super, or new.target keywords. Arrow function
> expressions are ill suited as methods, and they cannot be used as
> constructors.

```js
const myFunc = function({
  a = 'a',
  b = 'b',
  c = 'c'
} = {}){ console.log(arguments[0]) };

myFunc({a: 'a', b: 'b'})
```

Even with a regular function the default values are not assigned, you get only the truly used parameters.

Comment: no, you don't get default values, if an object is handed over.